# Difference between multiplied marginal probabilities and joint probability?

Tags: probability, distributions, independence, joint-distribution, marginal-distribution

For real-valued data $X$ and $Y$, what is the difference between

$$p(x,y) \quad \text{and} \quad p(x) p(y)$$
where their joint probabilities are (left), and multiplied probabilities (right), otherwise called "product of marginal probabilities".

More specifically, how is that difference affected when variables $X$ and $Y$ are

1. independent of each other
2. not independent from each other

i.e. what operations can or cannot be done in the presence or absence of independence? is there some list of probability laws or rules surrounding these two cases?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general if we have two RVs $X$ and $Y$ with well defined density or probability functions (continuous and discrete cases), the following hold:

$p(x,y) =   p(x|y) p(y) = p(y|x) p(x) $

if $X$ and $Y$ are independent we have that: $ p(x|y) = p(x)$ and $ p(y|x) = p(y)$  then:

$p(x,y) =   p(x) p(y) $

if them are not independent the product $p(x) p(y) $ do not have, at least in general, any relevant meaning.

Comment: are there variants or transformations that can help give the product of marginal probabilities $p(x) p(y)$ meaning? for example, multipling or adjusting them by some dependence measure like correlation suddenly makes them equal to the joint $p(x,y)$?

Comment: Among linear models/transformations, we can consider that, under independence or even scorrelation, the variance of the sum is given by the sum of single variances. In dependant cases the covariance term come in place. Maybe in general something like covariance (some dependency measure) can help to elaborate better your idea.